# How can I generate Spring REST services given a Database connection in IntelliJ?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

My MongoDB has lots of collections and want to expose a CRUD APIs to access them, but I dont want to spend time writing boiler plate code for each collection. 
I use IntelliJ as my official IDE and Spring Boot ( with Spring Data) as my framework.

Is there a tool/plugin which takes my DB connection as input, get all the collections and generate Pojos, beans,repository and service classes?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Telosys tools](https://www.telosys.org/) in order to get all the entities and repos in a minute. Then, I would suggest [Spring Data Rest](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) to expose all your collections.

An example of mongo templates for Telosys: [mongodb-templates](https://github.com/telosys-tools-beta/mongodb-springdata-TT300-sample-project/tree/master/TelosysTools/templates/mongodb-templates)

Comment: Telosys looks great but works only for a relational database, for SQL i already found lots of tools, my query is about MongoDB.

Comment: I agree, but you could create your own templates for mongodb and then execute it with telosys plugin in eclipse. I added an example of mongo templates

Comment: Telosys doesn't require necessarily a relational database, you can create a DSL model with all your entities and generate the data access layer for a NoSQL database (MongoDB, Redis, etc )

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a plugin or other tool to generate Spring Data Repos with just one click and doing this sufficently good.

I would suggest to use [File Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html) and [Intellij Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html).

File templates support [predefined and custom variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-template-variables.html#predefined_template_variables) and they are based on [apache velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/), so you can use the [Velocity Template Language (VTL)](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html).

Furthermore, you can use [live templates variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/live-template-variables.html) inside file templates when `Enable Live Templates` is active.

You should be able to create a Spring Data Repo within a few seconds with File and Live Templates.